# Get single JSON property value from response JSON using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit library (version 2.0.2 as of this writing).

I am making a GET call to a service which responds a big JSON object but I am only interested in one key:value pair in it.

How can I get just that instead of writing a whole new POJO class that matches the JSON response?

Example -

```
{
  status_code: 34,
  status_message: "The resource you requested could not be found.",
  ...,
  ...
}
```

I need only status code value (34 here).

Please note, I am just giving an example of this JSON object here. The real one I am dealing with is huge and I care about only one key:value pair in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the following:

```
@GET("/files/jsonsample.json")
Call<JsonObject> readJsonFromFileUri();
```

and

```
class MyStatus{
    int status_code;
}


...
Retrofit retrofit2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://...")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

WebAPIService apiService = retrofit2.create(WebAPIService.class);
Call<JsonObject> jsonCall = apiService.readJsonFromFileUri();
jsonCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        String jsonString = response.body().toString();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyStatus status = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyStatus.class);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(status.status_code));                
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, t.toString());
    }
});
...
```

Debug screenshot

[image]

Comment: So the name of the property in custom class (status_code in MyStatus here) has to match with JSON key?

Comment: Yes, don't you want so?

Comment: Oh no, I am cool with any name, but I am asking is this a requirement for it to work so that it knows what key it needs to extract from JSON?

Comment: Yes, you can try changing from `status_code` to `statuscode` inside MyStatus class, then you will see different result. If changing that, you need `class MyStatus{
        @SerializedName("status_code")
        int statuscode;
    }` for example. You can find more info at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home

Comment: can't you simply convert response to json object and get it by key. without using pojo class. `jsonObject.getString("status_code")`

Comment: @Pramodmishra yes, perhaps it's another way too, however, here I use `com.google.gson.JsonObject` not `org.json.JSONObject`, so you need to use the methods from `response.body()`

Comment: ok but finally you got string `String jsonString = response.body().toString();` then convert that string to json object and read if you want. you know that

Comment: @Pramodmishra I said it's also a way. The OP will choose the way he wants

Comment: Thank you for your answers, both answers work. I will stick with Gson though. In my case at least, I find it unnecessary to convert Gson -> String -> Json -> String (answer value) when Gson has all the methods I need to fetch a value for any key.